# Realizar una consulta con UPDATE en SQLITE

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

> Dividiendo en variables la consulta con acentos, comas, sumas y paréntesis

```
def actualizarDB(parametrosJSON):
    try:
        print("1")
        tabla = parametrosJSON["tabla"]
        colBusqueda = parametrosJSON["colBusqueda"]
        paramBusqueda = parametrosJSON["paramBusqueda"]
        datosNuevos = parametrosJSON["datosNuevos"]
        print("Datos obtenidos correctamente")
        clausulaIn = ''
        valores = None
        if tabla == 'Dispositivos':  
            print(parametrosJSON)
            clausulaIn = " UPDATE " + tabla + " SET " + colBusqueda + " = " + datosNuevos + " WHERE " + paramBusqueda + " = " + dato 

        con = sqlite3.connect(nombreBD)
        cursorObj = con.cursor()
        cursorObj.execute(clausulaIn)
        con.commit()
        con.close().
```

Comment: Puedes visualizar el contenido de clausulaIn para ver la construcción de la consulta?

Answer (score 0):

Una de las formas para realizar una consulta puede ser por medio del operador `%`

Utilizando tu mismo ejemplo:

```
clausulaIn = "UPDATE '%s' SET '%s'='%s' WHERE '%s'='%s'" % (tabla, colBusqueda, datosNuevos, paramBusqueda, dato)
```

Siempre considerando que todos los datos son de tipo `str` de lo contrario, si son `int` se deberán sustituir por `%d`

Saludos.